Problem getting Perl command line arguments
I just started learning Perl. I attempted to make a simple calculator that takes input from the command line.  Input: 5 * 10. Output: 50. But instead, it just prints 5. Here's the code:
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $op = $ARGV[1];
my $outpt = eval("return $ARGV[0]"."$op"."$ARGV[2]");
print "$outpt"."\n";

Any advice would be appreciated.
I tried to input all as one string instead, but that resulted in terminal output no matches found. How should I fix the error.

You know you could just eval "@ARGV", you don't have to try and quote every element.

Tip: eval('$ARGV[0]'."$op".'$ARGV[2]') makes more sense. No reason to interpolate $ARGV[0] and $ARGV[2].

Except if you really want to study the low-level fun of argument parsing, I guess you might be interested in Getopt::Long.

Your code work fine on my Win10 machine, however the result may vary in different platform. Perhaps you can tell what are you trying to achieve? like are you learning how eval() or @ARGV behave?

My guess is that you call this program from inside a shell. In this case the shell will interpret the arguments before it gets passed to the program. Specifically '*' gets replaced with the filenames in the current directory. So what you end up with in @ARGV depends on what is inside the current directory.
To prevent this replacement you can quote the argument or escape it:
$ perl test.pl 5 * 10
... output depends on content of directory

$ perl test.pl 5 \* 10
50

$ perl test.pl 5 "*" 10
50

Please note that the exact rules depend on the shell you are using, i.e. it might behave differently on UNIX shells vs. Windows cmd.

I'd use getopt:
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use 5.010;
use Getopt::Std;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
no warnings;

sub usage {
  my $msg = shift;
  say $0 . ' -m <multiplier> -n <multiplicand> ';
  say $msg;
  exit 1;
}

sub main {
  my $mult; #multiplier
  my $mcan; #multiplicand
  my $prod; #product
  my %options=();
  getopts("m:n:", \%options);
  if ( defined $options{m} && defined $options{n}) {
      $mult = $options{m};
      $mcan = $options{n};
  } else {
    usage "BAD ARGUMENTS";
}

if (!looks_like_number($mcan) ) {
   usage "BAD ARGUMENT -n $mcan";
}
if (!looks_like_number($mult) ) {
     usage "BAD ARGUMENT -m: $mult";
}
  $prod = $mult * $mcan;
  say "$mult * $mcan = $prod";
}

main;

./d.pl -m 3 -n 4
3 * 4 = 12
./d.pl -m 3 -n aasdfasd
BAD ARGUMENT -n aasdfasd
